# Local Notification Not Firing

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to use local notification, this is my code:

appdelegate

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [UIUserNotificationType.Sound, UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge], categories: nil))
```

*notificationViewController*

```
let localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()

var BDate = friend.birthday.componentsSeparatedByString("/")

let date = NSDate.date(year: 2015, month: Int(BDate[1])!, day: Int(BDate[0])! - daysBefore, hour: hour, minute: min, second: 0)
localNotification.soundName = "notificationSound.mp3"

localNotification.alertBody = friend.fullName + " has a birthday today!"

localNotification.fireDate = date
localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Year

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

friend.birthday is a string - "DD/MM/YYYY"

I'm calling the setNotification function for every friend in a friends array. When there are only one or two friends I get the notification but one there are ~100+ I no longer get the notification.

I know the fireDate is correct, I checked it.

Why the code isn't working?

Comment: fixed it, still not working

Comment: Have you checked the fire date you're setting then?

Comment: Yes, it's the correct date

Comment: @OmerN you need to set the timeZone before setting the fireDate

Answer (score 3):

Each app on a device is limited to 64 scheduled local notifications. The system discards scheduled notifications in excess of this limit, keeping only the 64 notifications that will fire the soonest. Recurring notifications are treated as a single notification.

[You can find more detail here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're really exceeded the notifications limit. There's several tips and guidelines that might help:

1. Try to check your `date` versus `NSDate()` and schedule notification only if `date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate > NSDate().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` (There is a `compare` method in `NSDate`, but I prefer to compare raw values)
2. Scheduling local notifications one-by-one is very expensive for application performance, so you can form an array of notifications and schedule them all at once. Use `UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications` property for that purpose.
3. This will allow you effectively reschedule all notifications on every application launch. For example in `applicationDidFinishLaunching()` delegate method.
4. And also, this will give you another advantage: you can easily check for notifications limit and, if necessary, add/replace 64-th notification with prompt to user to launch your app to allow it to schedule more notifications. This is a common practice for many applications to deal with Apple's limitations.